# Alternative way to read raw I/O stream in PHP

Tags: php, file-io, io

I am trying to find an alternative to reading php://input. I use this for getting XML data from a CURL PUT.

I usually do this with:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

However, I'm having a few issues with `file_get_contents()` on Windows.

Is there an alternative, perhaps using `fopen()` or `fread()`?

Comment: You should definitely use fopen and so on, file_get_contents is just a wrapper of those. Fopen is the most *low* level php code you can possibly get for handling file descriptors

Comment: probably related: [Best framework for PHP and Creation of RESTful based web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services)

Comment: using file() will return an array for you, using file_get_contents() will return a string for you, fopen will open the file but you need a protocol handler (php://) and you you have one.. Try to specify the extension of your file --- something like this --> fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");

Comment: @Antwan: Thanks. Could you direct me to an example of how I can do this?!

Comment: @Fernando: I'm not trying to read a file, I'm trying to read the contents of the IO stream to string.

Comment: file_get_contents is not exactly a wrapper for fopen-fread-flose because it will use mmap() if possible.

Comment: @Chuck Ugwuh goto http://www.w3schools.com -- you should find the correct information you need there, or you could give php.net a try, which is more extended

Comment: Guys, he's not looking for **files** because [`php://input` allows you to read raw data from the **request body**.](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) (hence my suggestion to use  REST framework instead of doing it by hand)

Comment: then try use fread($fileopened, filesize($filename));

Comment: *(tip)* http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.http.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
$f = fopen('php://input', 'r');
if (!$f)  die("Couldn't open input stream\n");
$data = '';
while ($buffer =  fread($f, 8192)) $data .= $buffer;
fclose($f);
```

But, the question you have to ask yourself is why isn't `file_get_contents` working on windows?  Because if it's not working, I doubt `fopen` would work for the same stream...

Comment: This works, but shouldn't I be worried if the XML data that I'm 'PUTting' (so to speak) is greater than 8192 bytes?!

Comment: And I believe the file_get_contents() issue is some Windows bug.

Comment: That's why the loop.  if you look at the docs for [`fread`](http://us.php.net/fread), you'll see that it won't always read the entire requested length.  So instead, it's typically seen as better practice to loop while reading to make up for cases when it doesn't read the entire thing (it's more robust)...

Answer (score 3):

Ok. I think I've found a solution.

```
$f = @fopen("php://input", "r");
$file_data_str = stream_get_contents($f);
fclose($f);
```

Plus, with this, I'm not mandated to put in a file size.